# 2 similar Haskell functions using do notation return same result but one is called many more times

Tags: haskell, recursion, optimization

```
nextState :: IO Int -> IO Int -- 0 1 0 2 0 1 0
nextState stateIO = do
  value <- stateIO
  putStrLn $ "Current state: " ++ show value
  fmap (+1) stateIO

nextState' :: IO Int -> IO Int -- 0 1 2
nextState' stateIO = do
  value <- stateIO
  putStrLn $ "Current state: " ++ show value
  return $ value + 1

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let startStateIO = return 0 :: IO Int
  let states = iterate nextState' startStateIO -- Use nextState or nextState'
  stateInt <- states !! 3
  print stateInt -- 3 in both cases
```

This Haskell code has 2 functions which both seemingly have identical behavior. However, printing calls shows that `nextState` is being called a lot more times than `nextState'`.
I had a larger project where this was an issue and I couldn't figure out how to convert that function so that it was called the minimum number of times so I couldn't fix it.

Why does this happen and how can I prevent it in a less simple example?

Note that `fmap (+1)` in my actual project is just a function from `IO a -> IO a`, not `fmap (a -> a)` - the whole thing works in terms of IO, not modifying the values inside using `(a->a)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be easier to understand this example, which is analogous:

```
twice :: IO () -> IO ()
twice act = do
   () <- act
   fmap id act -- like what you did in `nextState`

once :: IO () -> IO ()
once act = do
   () <- act
   return $ id ()  -- like what you did in `nextState'`
```

...or shorter

```
twice :: IO () -> IO ()
twice act = act >> act

once :: IO () -> IO ()
once act = act
```

For example,

```
> twice (putStrLn "hello")
hello
hello
> once (putStrLn "hello")
hello
```

Iterating `once` doesn't do anything, because it's just the identity.

```
> iterate once (putStrLn "hello") !! 4
hello
```

Iterating twice, however...

```
Prelude> iterate twice (putStrLn "hello") !! 4
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
```